# Find conflicts in two different CSS files

Tags: web-apps, web-development, programming, css

Is there a tool where I can upload/(or add content of files in textboxes) two CSS files and it shows me the conflicting css rules?

## Example

### foo.css

```
body { font-size: 1rem; }
...
.nav { background: yellow; }
...
.header { font-size: 12px; }
...
```

### bar.css

```
body { font-size: 1.4rem; }
...
.nav { background: red; }
...
.header { font-color: black; }
...
```

## conflicts found after tool ran:

```
foo.css: body { font-size: 1rem; }
bar.css: body { font-size: 1.4rem; }

foo.css: .nav { background: yellow; }
bar.css: .nav { background: red; }
```

This would help me to identifiy conflicts and find a fix. Otherwise I have to open the developer tools and manually go through each html element on the site and search for conflicts.

### fix.css

In fix.css which I am creating manually (or by the tool) I can decide which css of these two files should get loaded:

```
body { font-size: 1.4rem; }
.nav { background: yellow; }
```

Comment: Welcome Black! You are looking for a web-app (online tool), correct?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, I am also ok with any other application, but web application would be preferably.

Comment: Sounds good. If it's not a web-app, which operating system(s) should it run under?

Comment: Preferable windows

Comment: You are looking for an automated tool. For single CSS rules, where you are unsure, right click the HTMl page element and choose "inspect" - you will see which rule applies, and also which it overrides.

Comment: would be good to have such a tool if anyone knows